# Arduino sync issue, 13 not blinking, 2 arduino's deads?

Tags: arduino, icsp

So, here's a copy of the problem I've mentionned on the arduino forum thinking they could help me, but no answers there. Here's the issue :

```
avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : \\.\COM3
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: 
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

The arduino is correctly recognized by the computer. The drivers are ok too. The com port is ok.

Without any solution, I've swapped the atmega328 from another arduino with faulty one. Before that I've just uploaded the blink 13 code to the working one, no problem. Once the new chip is on the faulty one I now have the same issue on both arduino bords. 13 is not blinking 3 times at the begining, just stays always high, and they can't be programmed. And now the previously working one is not working anymore on his intial board too ! :'(

Also, RX blink three times when programmed (correspond to the three sends). And when I use a serial terminal to send data to the arduino, RX is blinking too.

A preicison, the pin13 L is not bright, looks like dimmed.
Also I've actually configured my last uno as an ISP. When I try to upload the code to my faulty arduino I get :

```
avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : \\.\COM5
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [80]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [02] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [01] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [12] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [98]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [84]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [85]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [86]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [87]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [89]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [01] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [12] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: B [42] . [86] . [00] . [00] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [03] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [00] . [80] . [04] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [80] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: E [45] . [05] . [04] . [d7] . [c2] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: P [50]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | avrdude: Send: V [56] 0 [30] . [00] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] 0 [30] . [00] . [01] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
################avrdude: Send: V [56] 0 [30] . [00] . [02] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
################################## | 100% 0.06s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: Send: Q [51]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

So, I got the same device signature error even when I want to burn the bootloader. The -F doesn't change anything, the upload succeed but the programmed arduino is not working.

If you have any ideas, troobleshooting idea or anything let me know. I continue to try to track down the problem, if I get something new I'll notice you.

And big thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit**
If I'm programmins the atmega328 directly with ICSP (without passing through the arduino board, on a breadboard) the chips are all working. So I think it's coming from the board it self. But as I don't have oscilloscope "only" multimeters and logic analyzer, the troobleshooting will not be easy. If you have any ideas.

**EDIT2**
If I put the working chip back to the arduino board, I get a voltage on the correct output. But really low and not blinking. But only the output mentionned in the sketch is high. Dead regulator ?

**EDIT 3**
With the chip on the board. The voltage regulator is ok. The atmega328 AREF is 4.99V, AVCC 4.25V, VCC 4.26V. 
Led L attached to D13 is 1.83V.
Measure between D9 on the chip and the ground on the same chip give me 4.8V. Measure between D9 on the chip and D9 pin gives me 2.3V.

**EDIT 4**
I start to think the problem comes from the ATMega16U2 chip. But the measurements seems ok.

**EDIT 5**
Voltage on the reset pin of the atmega328 always remain high, even when I press the reset button on the uno... (but is correctly goeing to 0 on the button, so button itself is ok)

**EDIT 6**
After further investigation, the reset pin on the 16U2 isn't set to low when pressing the reset button too. [According to the uno schematics.](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf) I suspect C5 of being dead. RN2D is ok.

**EDIT 7**
I have re-flashed the ATMega16U2 firmware. Problem persist.

Comment: Does the board reset when you start programming it from the IDE? The bootloader in the ATmega only runs directly after reset. You can try pushing the board's reset button at the same time you click the upload button in the IDE. Which brings us to the question which exact board you use.

Comment: Are you getting anything off the crystal?

Comment: @jippie : It's an uno, change nothing and don't really think it's related to the issue.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : Yes, to be sure I've desolder it from one of the faulty uno board and put it on a breadboard with the atmega328, it's working.

Comment: @jippie : but if I measure the voltage between atmega328 reset and ground, when I press or not the reset button he always remains high. (but he's correctly going to 0 on the button, so button itself is ok)

Comment: Does the 16U2 respond if you connect the ICSP to it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : I'll try. But I've also found that when I press the reset button down the 16U2 reset pin isn't set to low too. So I start to suspect C5 (http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf) of being dead. I check C5 and I try to connect to the 16U5 with ICSP.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : I'm able to connect to him. I've also reflash the 16u2 to be sure the firmware wasn't corrupted. Nothing changes, still the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so, after 9h of research I figured out the problem. Since 9h I was putting the chip... (prepare to laugh) in the wrong direction...

[image]

I... I'm sorry... really...

And yes you can laugh...

So the answer to that issue is : Put the chip in the correct direction.

Comment: Facepalm award! :-) Must admit, it was quite brave of you to publish to the world what really happened!

Comment: Bwahahahahahaha awesome. I hate it when something like that happens.

Comment: Just so you don't feel alone, I'll admit to doing the same thing recently. I was ready to blame Windows 8 as the source of my problem, as it was my first time programming an arduino on my new laptop. (I have done it successfully many times in the past on Win XP and Mac) After several hours of screwing around, I remembered that I had removed the chip recently and decided to check the polarity. It was backwards. To my surprise, it worked fine after switching it back to the correct orientation. It can happen to any of us.

Comment: I was recently working on soldering up some power to a string of holiday lights.  Would not work, could not get it to work.  It's the right voltage!  Why doesn't this work?  What the hell is wrong?  My joints are good!  Oh.  It helps if you turn it on.  We've all done it.